# missing LinuxMain.swift file

Tags: swift, vapor

Running `swift test` with Swift 5.1 or later complains about missing LinuxMain.swift file.

```
$ swift test
error: missing LinuxMain.swift file in the Tests directory
```

Answer (score 3):

When using Swift 5.1 or later, use the `--enable-test-discovery` flag to bypass LinuxMain.swift.

```
swift test --enable-test-discovery
```

More info here: https://forums.swift.org/t/test-discovery-on-linux/26203